# Resolving Salesforce cyclic dependency between Outbound Messaging and API updates

Tags: wcf, soap, salesforce, soap-client

I have set up a Salesforce Dev account which sends out an Outbound Message to a WCF Service every time a record (Opportunity) is created or updated.

This WCF Service being the endpoint URL for the Oubound Message, handles the notifications and then also calls back the Salesforce account to make an update using the standard Salesforce API (I am using SOQL for this)

It all works very well until the outbound message is received and processed by the WCF service but then the issue begins.

The moment I call back the Salesforce API from within the WCF service for updating a record, the Outbound message gets fired again kick starting another outbound message.

My requirement is only to send out the Outbound message when the insert/update to a record in Salesforce is performed manually and not via API.

Is there a ready-made solution to this that Salesforce provides or do I need to handle this myself.

I believe there must be a better, more elegant way of doing this?

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
-Sumit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom profile for the user account that is making the API calls, on this profile you can uncheck the "Send Outbound Messages" permission in the "Administrative Permissions" section. This will stop the notification loop you're seeing.